# gdb print array of soft array

Tags: c++, c, gdb

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
typedef struct _soft_array
{
    int len;
    int array[];//int array[0];
}SoftArray;

int main()
{  
    int i = 0;
    SoftArray* sa = (SoftArray*)malloc(sizeof(SoftArray) + sizeof(int) * 10);

    sa->len = 10;

    for(i=0; i<sa->len; i++)
    {
        sa->array[i] = i + 1;
    }

    for(i=0; i<sa->len; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", sa->array[i]);   
    }

    free(sa);

    return 0;
}
```

I use gdb to print the array of sa->array,then something confuse me:

```
(gdb) p sa->array
$1 = 0x602014
(gdb) p *sa->array@10
$2 = {[0] = 1, [1] = 2, [2] = 3, [3] = 4, [4] = 5, [5] = 6, [6] = 7, [7] = 8, [8] = 9, [9] = 10}
(gdb) p sizeof(int)
$3 = 4
(gdb) p *(char *)0x602014@40
$4 = "\001\000\000\000\002\000\000\000\003\000\000\000\004\000\000\000\005\000\000\000\006\000\000\000\a\000\000\000\b\000\000\000\t\000\000\000\n\000\000"
(gdb)
```

the first method went well (I add set print array-indexes on in .gdbinit).

sizeof(int)==4,then I use p *(char *)0x602014@40,due to my computer is little-endian，so 1 display with 01 00 00 00.

When display 7,the output become a?

How does that happen or I miss something ?

Comment: Are you perhaps debugging an optimized build? If so, the debugging experience is not reliable.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the output isn't the character `'a'`, but `'\a'`. That is the *alert* character, in [ASCII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii). Just like you later get `'\b'` and `'\t'` and `'\n'` for the ASCII equivalents of those characters.

[This character escape reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/escape) contains a list of all standard C escape characters, together with their ASCII encoded values.

Comment: not familiar with Escape sequences,reading the article learn much.command p *(char *)0x602014@40 just print every byte in octal,this is unusual for me.